# Versioning of entity values

Tags: c#, entity, versioning

I'm looking for a way to version the values of my entities.

Examples:

- If I have a blog post I would like to save every version of it every time I change it.
- If I have a user account I would like to save the phone number and email every time the user changes it, such that I can access previous versions of the phone number and email.

Is there a special pattern for this?

How could it be implemented in C#?

Comment: Second feature looks problematic from a privacy point of view. When I edit out my phone number, I expect it to be actually removed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Jason Dentler's book ([http://www.amazon.com/NHibernate-3-0-Cookbook-Jason-Dentler/dp/184951304X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/184951304X)). `Chapter 1. Handling versioning and concurrency` describes how to mantain versioning. Book describes common approaches on using NHibernate ORM.

Good Luck!

Comment: This describes concurrency, not how to actually have more versions of the 'same' entity in DB.